# Bootstrap Datatable is no longer functioning after loading content via Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables, bootstrap-4

Before some one says its a duplicate question, i know it is. I've just not been able to find anyone's script that looks similar to mine and as i'm completely new to JavaScript and JQuery (used to php) i don't really know what I'm doing.

My datatable worked perfectly having the data loaded using php (before the page had loaded) but now its loaded after the page load, the table has lost all of it's filtering and pagination.

Here is how my table is loaded.

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <?php echo $tableheader;?>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <?php echo $tableheader;?>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody id="data"> <!--data will be inputed here-->

        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

This is the script that gets the data and puts it into the table.

```
<script>
    //call ajax
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest ();
    var method = "GET";
    var url = "data_assets.php";
    var asynchronous = true;

    setInterval(function(){
        ajax.open(method, url, asynchronous);
        //sending ajax request
        ajax.send();
    }, 250)

    //receiving response from data_assets.php
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            //convert JSON back to array
            var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            //console.log(data); //for debugging

            //html value for <tbody>
            var html ="";

            //looping through the data
            for (var a = 0; a < data.length; a++) {
                var asset_number = data[a].asset_number;
                var id = data[a].id;
                var room = data[a].room;
                var _location = data[a]._location;
                var sku = data[a].sku;
                var qty = data[a].qty;
                var _value = data[a]._value;
                var date = data[a].date;
                var po_number = data[a].po_number;
                var purchaced_from = data[a].purchaced_from;
                var notes = data[a].notes;
                var total = data[a].total;

                //storing in html
                html += "<tr>";
                    html += "<td style='vertical-align: middle;'>" + asset_number + "</td>";
                    html += "<td style='vertical-align: middle;'>" + id + "</td>";
                    html += "<td style='vertical-align: middle;'>" + room + "</td>";
                    html += "<td style='vertical-align: middle;'>" + _location + "</td>";
                    html += "<td style='vertical-align: middle;'>" + sku + "</td>";
                    html += "<td style='vertical-align: middle;'>" + qty + "</td>";
                    html += "<td style='vertical-align: middle;'>" + _value + "</td>";
                    html += "<td style='vertical-align: middle;'>" + total + "</td>";
                    html += "<td style='text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;'>" + date + "</td>";
                    html += "<td style='vertical-align: middle;'>" + po_number + "</td>";
                    html += "<td style='vertical-align: middle;'>" + purchaced_from + "</td>";
                    html += "<td style='vertical-align: middle;'>" + notes + "</td>";
                    html += "<td style='text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;'>";
                        html += "<a href='?id=" + id + "&room=" + room + "&asset=" + asset_number + "&location=" + _location + "&sku=" + sku + "&qty=" + qty + "&value=" + _value + "&date=" + date + "&po=" + po_number + "&where=" + purchaced_from + "&notes=" + notes + "#editModal' class=''><i class='far fa-edit fa-lg'></i></a>";
                    html += "</td>";
                    html += "<td style='text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;'>";
                        html += "<a href='?id=" + id + "&room=" + room + "&asset=" + asset_number + "&location=" + _location + "&sku=" + sku + "&qty=" + qty + "&value=" + _value + "&date=" + date + "&po=" + po_number + "&where=" + purchaced_from + "&notes=" + notes + "#duplicateModal' class=''><i class='far fa-clone fa-lg'></i></a>";
                    html += "</td>";
                html += "</tr>";
            }

            //replacing the <tbody> 
            document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = html;
        }
    }
</script>
```

If anyone could show me how to get this working in my example it would be greatly appreciated, I really want to load all of my tables on this site like this so i dont need to have a refresh on saving data (This refreshes every 250ms so the data in the table is always up to date with the database).

Update:

Right i took out my 250ms refresh and now the table works perfectly! is anyone now able to help me with my next issue. How do i get the table to refresh when new data is entered into the database, without refreshing the whole page

Comment: That's a lot of refreshes. like 1200 in 5 minutes

Comment: If you uncomment this line `//console.log(data); //for debugging` what does it output? Can you please update the answer with that info?

Comment: it shows the data in the array in the inspect element console. it litteraly just contains the data that is in the table

Comment: @LegenJerry is that a problem having that many refreshes? i looked at load on my pc and it didnt seem to do anything major and the server is beefy. its only running a mysql query so i didnt think it would be a major issue. Is there another way to have it show new database entries when one is created? or only like how ive done it?

Comment: It does seem like a lot. I don't know what type of application you're building but do you expect data to be constantly written to the database every quarter second or faster?

Comment: @LegenJerry Yeah i did think it was too much but i just wanted the table to show the new data when you click save on the form, without refreshing the whole page. It turned out that the refresh is what was breaking the table, so ive removed it now. now i just need to know how to auto update the table when new data is written to the database

Comment: @CarlPiper check out my answer, I updated it. According to the DataTables API there is a method for refreshing tables. The fiddle I provided will need modification to suit your application but If it answers your question could you mark it accepted, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest creating the table structure in HTML or PHP (not Javascript). Then load the data into the table with ajax. Those DOM elements are not readily available to javascript unless the event to create the elements is bound to an element that already exists like `body` or `document` or some other parent element of the table.

**UPDATE:**

I personally don't have much experience with DataTables plugin. So the plugin will automatically create your DOM elements (table structure) based on either the `data` object returned from ajax or by properties you specify. DataTables does use jQuery's `ajax()` method to make ajax calls however you should not override the `success` callback. There is a proper way to use their API when making ajax calls as specified in the documentation. There is also a proper way to reload data on an interval to refresh your tables.

Please check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9p748xLu/159/).

The ajax `url, method, data` properties must of course be updated to fit your application (this was the only way to simulate ajax call on jsFiddle. Please note you will have to have properly formatted JSON.

Comment: Sorry i'm not sure I understand what you mean. I thought i was making the table structure in the php only adding the <td>'s using javascript. When i say im new to javascript, i really am extremely new. I understand why and when to use it and roughly have it works but i couldn't code it myself, only using tutorials at the moment. of course i do really want to learn which is why im starting to impliment it more in more in my projects.

Comment: Ok. I'm working on a fiddle to see if I can help you

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I updated my answer with a demonstration. Check out the console to see that the data should continue to be reloaded. You should verify this on your server by updating rows in the database while your application is running to see if it actually works.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to explicitly set pagelength property on Datatables?

```
$('#datatable').dataTable( {
  "pageLength": 50
} );
```

Comment: The table and the data loads just fine, it's just it breaks the Datatables pagination and stuff. The table is all there and filled with data

Comment: You mean to custom limit displayed rows in Datatable by means of pagination?

Comment: before when i loaded the data with php the table was limited to 10 items per page and you could click through the pages. but now all of the data is shown on the page