# DataTables fill table from JSON or JS Array&Objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatable

I have a table that I was filling it with jquery(html). In order to limit displaying rows I have been trying to change this table to datatables.

I have this kind of data:

```
dataArray = [{
    id: 1,
    props: {
        abc: 123,
        def: 456,
        ghi: 789
    },
    features: {
        zxc: 01,
        cvb: 02,
        nmn: 03
    }
},
{
    id: 2,
    props: {
        abc: 002,
        def: 258,
        ghi: 965
    },
    features: {
        zxc: 52,
        cvb: 21,
        nmn: 75
    }
},
{
    id: 3,
    props: {
        abc: 352,
        def: 365,
        ghi: 778
    },
    features: {
        zxc: 21,
        cvb: 45,
        nmn: 03
    }
},
```

]

Lets say, I would like to display **id**, **abc**(from props), **zxc**(from features).

I tried to use in datatable by converting JSON but it didnt work. I am not sure how I can display this data on the datatable.

This dataArray is updated inside of the app, it is not external data.

Could you help me please?

Comment: you can read this reference on how to display nested JSON data in jquery datatables : http://infra.clarin.eu/content/libs/DataTables-1.10.6/examples/ajax/objects_subarrays.html
note in javascript code you should replace ajax attribute with your dataArray object.

Comment: Please check out my solution. If it answered your question can you mark it accepted, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to change your JSON properties and their corresponding values to strings as far as I know. If you need to do any arithmetic on the integers you could always `parseInt()`. Then in your `DataTable()` call specify `data` and `columns` properties like so:

```js
var dataArray = [{
    "id": "1",
    "props": {
        "abc": "123",
        "def": "456",
        "ghi": "789"
    },
    "features": {
        "zxc": "01",
        "cvb": "02",
        "nmn": "03"
    }
},
{
    "id": "2",
    "props": {
        "abc": "002",
        "def": "258",
        "ghi": "965"
    },
    "features": {
        "zxc": "52",
        "cvb": "21",
        "nmn": "75"
    }
},
{
    "id": "3",
    "props": {
        "abc": "352",
        "def": "365",
        "ghi": "778"
    },
    "features": {
        "zxc": "21",
        "cvb": "45",
        "nmn": "03"
    }
},
]

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        data: dataArray,
        "columns": [
            { data: "id" },
            { data: "props.abc" },
            { data: "features.zxc" },
        ]
    } );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Props</th>
            <th>Features</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Props</th>
            <th>Features</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: Nice solution bro !

it sounds like this reference example : http://infra.clarin.eu/content/libs/DataTables-1.10.6/examples/ajax/objects_subarrays.html

Comment: I didn’t see that. I read the documentation and api reference. I don’t have much experience with datatables plugin so I learned a thing or two today! I just answered a second question after this with a table refresh and ajax using the plugin. More people should read docs/reference, I agree, if that’s what you are insinuating. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51671793/bootstrap-datatable-is-no-longer-functioning-after-loading-content-via-ajax/51672059#51672059

Comment: No i didn't mean any thing bad. 
I upvoted for your answer.in my opinion it's a good solution and it's like the reference i mentioned in the comment.

Comment: @Oghli oh cool thanks. Yea it’s pretty straightforward when you look at some references

Comment: @CanerSezgin No Problem! Keep in mind you may have issues with those values that have leading zeros. You will need to find a solution to pad those values if you convert them to integers. As strings they are fine though.

Comment: @LegenJerry, Now I have another problem, I can not update table. What should i do ? Normally I was using $('tableName').html(''); and .append all cells but now I cant update cells when the data is changed. 
This is the Proplem that i recieved when the data changed

****DataTables warning: table id=table_results - Cannot reinitialise DataTable. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/3*****

Comment: Is your data loaded with ajax?

Comment: https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().data() For row data, https://datatables.net/reference/api/cell().data() For cell data, https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload() For ajax data

Comment: No I just directly use array, (data: dataArray)  and the objects values are changing inside this array. I am not sure which one is mine :) What do you think type of the array (dataArray) that you used in your solution

Comment: @CanerSezgin check out this fiddle it simulates data change. Please familiarize yourself with DataTables documentation. It is all there. http://jsfiddle.net/ym874f0x/13/