# How to split and fuse?

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

I have a problem:
I have this database:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
| Germany         | Italy               | Belgium              |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
| Gerhard Richter | Leonardo da Vinci   | Anton van Dyck       |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
| Paul Klee       | Sandro Botticelli   | Michaël Borremans    |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
| Neo Rauch       | Masaccio            | Paul Delvaux         |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to add in one row a value of each row instead of each column:

Here image: https://puu.sh/B81Po/03395bad74.png

I added a `.split(", ");` but now is dividing each row into 3 rows which is okay but I need to add the other column values too.

The code:

```js
const Obj = {
    "0":"Neo Rauch, Paul Klee, Gerhard Richter",
    "1":"Masaccio, Sandro Botticelli, Leonardo da Vinci",
    "2":"Paul Delvaux, Michaël Borremans, Anton van Dyck"  
};

const Obj2 = {}
Object.keys(Obj).forEach(function(key) {
  Obj2[key] = Obj[key].split(", ");
});

console.log(Obj2);
```

EDIT:
How is now:

```
"0":"Neo Rauch, Paul Klee, Gerhard Richter",
"1":"Masaccio, Sandro Botticelli, Leonardo da Vinci",
"2":"Paul Delvaux, Michaël Borremans, Anton van Dyck"
```

How i want it:

```
"0":"Neo Rauch", "Masaccio", "Paul Delvaux"
"1":"Paul Klee", "Sandro Botticelli", "Michaël Borremans"
"2":"Gerhard Richter", "Leonardo da Vinci", "Anton van Dyck"
```

Comment: `fuse`? Do you mean `join`?

Comment: do you mean you want like { Germany: Macaccio, Italiy: "Sandro", Belgium: "Gerhard" }

Comment: Yes. I mean to join, just when redacting to my head came the fuse word.

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: Updated the post at the bottom there's how I need. Thanks!

Comment: @LegenJerry I don't need to reference my table column names, I need to do this using the created object.

Comment: @K3ny1 Please check out my answer I think this is what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is not a properly formatted object and will result in syntax errors. Here is one way to get what I believe is your desired result.

The first console out is nested objects, and the second is an object with nested arrays.

```js
const Obj = {
    "0":"Neo Rauch, Paul Klee, Gerhard Richter",
    "1":"Masaccio, Sandro Botticelli, Leonardo da Vinci",
    "2":"Paul Delvaux, Michaël Borremans, Anton van Dyck"  
};

const Obj2 = {};
const Obj3 = {};

Object.keys(Obj).forEach(function(key) {
    var string = [];
    Object.keys(Obj).forEach(function(k) {
     string.push(Obj[k].split(", ")[key]);
    });

    var obj = string.reduce(function(acc, cur, i) {
        acc[i] = cur;
        return acc;
    }, {});

    Obj2[key] = obj;
    Obj3[key] = string;
});

console.log(Obj2);
console.log(Obj3);
```

Comment: Hello @LegendJerry you are a legend as your name!! I'm almost making it works, but I'm having some troubles to add it to my script. Can we have some kind of chat on google/skype or whatever you use?

Many thanks!!

Comment: @K3ny1 Awesome! If that answered your original question could you please accept my answer? I can help you how with incorporating it in your script, but I don't use skype. You can use this pen https://codepen.io/legenjerry/pen/zLaRKO . I'll try to update accordingly. Leave comments on it and fork it.

Comment: Hello check i added comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pZKapB?editors=0012 thanks!

Comment: @LegendJerr you see the message? Thanks!

Comment: All you have to do is change the object declaration to an array https://codepen.io/legenjerry/pen/NBzyQm?editors=1111

Comment: @LegendJerry Thank you so much man!! That was very smart! BTW: If you come to chat (1-2 minutes) may you be interested thanks again!

Comment: @LegendJerry Hello again, your script works perfect, but I have a problem. If I add new values one of the values it doesn't get processed. Seems like the script is prepared to 3 values. Can you please show me how I can do it dynamically? I mean my idea is to use it for a database that I don't know how much rows has. Maybe 3 or maybe 100 you know? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mjKxMa?editors=0012

Thanks so much again!!

Comment: This was an example I did for someone else with a similar problem http://jsfiddle.net/ym874f0x/13/ it simulates adding data to a data table. You can adapt it to work with your script

Comment: Thanks for the link but I don't see the similarity between my case and that case. I'm loading data from a database no pre-defined. Your plugin was working awesome just I don't know why is not loading the new items and only keeps on those 3. I thought your script will work no matters how many things are inside the Obj. Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51671859/datatables-fill-table-from-json-or-js-arrayobjects/51672888#comment90319654_51672888

Comment: Those links in my comment are the api references for refreshing your datatables. The fiddle I made is an example

Comment: Yeah, I understand but I'm loading the data at page loads. Btw if you check the script: (I added a new row): https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yqEKdb?editors=0012 You will see in console there are undefined items. Thanks!

Comment: Any idea? What could be happening? Thanks!

Comment: you still there?

Comment: @K3ny1 this is the last one https://codepen.io/legenjerry/pen/pZKVVa?editors=1111 Your requirements are changing and I don't have the time to keep up with your application.

Comment: Yes, I should explain at the begin that I need to be dynamic data. Works perfectly this time LegenJerry. Thank you so much for your time. You really helped me. I hope you have a great day! Regards!!

Comment: Hello, again @LegenJerry how are you? Hope everything is fine! I have to say that entire week your code was working crazy fine! I think its a marvelous creation!! My congratulations for that. But I'm trying to solve an issue that I'm facing. In some cases, I have to add in one "cell" words with commas like Leonardo, di, Caprio. But actually, the plugin is splitting that in 3 different values. Do you think it's possible to the values that have this 'quotes' the commas inside don't touch them? Like consider it is an entire word: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vavZqm?editors=1111

Comment: You should post a new question so other people have an opportunity to answer. However if you do then just reply to this comment and I’ll try to answer your new question

Comment: Thank you @LegenJerry, you are true. I have created a new post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51778069/split-and-fuse-words hope someone helps me to do add that small change to your awesome code.

Answer (score 0):

You can join your array with "," so that you get double quotes around your each words. Hope this is how you want.

```js
const Obj = {
    "0":"Neo Rauch, Paul Klee, Gerhard Richter",
    "1":"Masaccio, Sandro Botticelli, Leonardo da Vinci",
    "2":"Paul Delvaux, Michaël Borremans, Anton van Dyck"  
};

const Obj2 = {}
Object.keys(Obj).forEach(function(key) {
  Obj2[key] = Obj[key].split(", ").join('","');
});

console.log(Obj2);
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but it doesn't only change the quotes. I need to get the first value of each column and create a new row.