# Split and Fuse words

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

Actually, I have this piece of code that takes the Words inside the Obj and it separates creating a new row for each column (this actually works perfectly), and it's exactly what I want. But I've noticed on some cases I have in the same group words separated by a comma.

Example:
"Masaccio, Sandro Botticelli, Leonardo da Vinci"
We have here 3 words. The code generates a new row from those 3 words.

But what happens when I have this?
"Masaccio, Sandro Botticelli, Leonardo, da, Vinci"
The script thinks there we have 5 words.
So my question is: how I should create something like this:
"Masaccio, Sandro Botticelli, 'Leonardo, da, Vinci'"
Using this 'quotes' to consider it as only one word instead of 3.

Any ideas?
Thanks!!

```js
const Obj = {
    "0":"Masaccio, Sandro Botticelli, Leonardo da Vinci",
    "1":"Random, Thing, Uploaded",
    "2":"String, Second String, Third string",
    "3":"Chef, Police, Cat",
    "4":"Legen, Jerry, Jack",
};

const Obj3 = [];

var count = Obj[0].split(", ").length;
var countOuter = Object.keys(Obj).length;

for( var i = 0; i < count; i++){
  
  var string = [];
  
  for( var j = 0; j < countOuter; j++){
    string.push(Obj[j].split(", ")[i]);
  }
  
  Obj3[i] = string;
}

console.log(Obj3);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility would be to create a regular expression to `match` comma-separated words (no quotes `'` allowed), OR match a starting `'` quote up until its matching ending `'`:

```js
const Obj = {
    "0":"Masaccio, Sandro Botticelli, 'Leonardo, da, Vinci'",
    "1":"Random, Thing, Uploaded",
    "2":"String, Second String, Third string",
    "3":"Chef, Police, Cat",
    "4":"Legen, Jerry, Jack",
};
const result = Object.values(Obj).reduce((a, str) => {
  const items = str.match(/\w[\w\s]+(?=, |$)|'[^']+'/g);
  items.forEach((item, i) => {
    if (!a[i]) a[i] = [];
    a[i].push(item);
  });
  return a;
}, []);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @CertainPerformance. After testing the code I've noticed there some issues:
1- When using a . as the last character on a word, gets a wrong split. I:E:
"Random., Thing, Uploaded"
2- The problem I'm facing it's I don't know how to do this scenario:
As I said, when separating words sometimes there are some words, that using, and the script is separating them in different words. How could avoid that?

Thanks!!

Comment: If you want to include periods and not just word characters / spaces, then add a period to the character set. `[\w\s.]`

Comment: Hello, @CertainPerformance thank you so much for your answer. I'm facing a problem. Is there any way to have a live chat to explain you my problem? I can pay you for your time. Thanks!

Comment: We can chat on chat.stackoverflow.com once you get enough reputation for the privilege (20 rep)

Comment: Hello @CertainPerfomance, please check this codepen, I updated the format of the Obj, so I need to do exactly what is doing right now but with this new format. Is this possible? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vzOWBq?editors=0011 
thanks!!

Comment: Do you think it's possible? It's just I'm stuck. Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: That is quite a malformed array. I would recommend fixing whatever generates it first, at the moment it's quite unclear what its structure is intended to be.

Comment: Sorry about that @CertainPerformance this is how looks the console.log on my website: https://puu.sh/BiMF4/b88b523ec6.png But I'm not sure how to create that sample on the codepen. Thanks!

Comment: I think those are all single strings? Looks like you should just `split` by `'","'`

Comment: Okay, I solved the problem!! Man, you are a best!! Just with that simple tip, I did the fix! Thank you soooo much!!. Can I ask you my last question? I promise.

How I can do this: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jvPaYa?editors=0011
So the result will be this: https://puu.sh/BiNaS/5a1fb17374.png

Comment: Looks like the separators are `, `, so just split by that and use the same method as before